# Inserting data into a database - SQLException

Tags: java, mysql, sqlexception

I'm trying to insert information entered by a user from a Java GUI I made on NetBeans but I keep getting an exception I can't seem to find out what I did wrong. (Database name is student and table is also called student(I know bad) it has 8 columns but I'm just testing the first 7 because the last one is complicated)

```
 private void AddBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
String Fname;
String Lname;
String Email;
Integer age;
String num;
String gen = null;
Integer stuId;

Connection conn=null;
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student", "root","Splash7727#" );
     String query="insert into student.student values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";
     PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
     stuId=Integer.parseInt(ITxt.getText());
     pst.setInt(1,stuId);
     pst.setString(2,Fname=FnTxt.getText());
     pst.setString(3,Lname=LnTxt.getText());
         if(FRBtn.isSelected())
{
    gen="Female";
}
else if(MRBtn.isSelected())
{
    gen="Male";
}

     pst.setString(4, gen);
     age=Integer.parseInt(ageTxt.getText());
     pst.setInt(5,age);
     pst.setString(6, num=NumTxt.getText());
     pst.setString(6,Email=EmTxt.getText());
     pst.executeUpdate();

}catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Original stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 7
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1115)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
at wecare.Add.AddBtnActionPerformed(Add.java:266)
at wecare.Add.access$000(Add.java:14)
at wecare.Add$1.actionPerformed(Add.java:75)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

New Stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
at wecare.Add.AddBtnActionPerformed(Add.java:266)
at wecare.Add.access$000(Add.java:14)
at wecare.Add$1.actionPerformed(Add.java:75)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: the one i had written there the "Error" message at the end

Comment: *"..from netbeans"* The same way you'd do it from Eclipse or IntelliJ. In other words, the IDE has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

throw error or print the stack trace and paste the complete error message here instead of printing "Error" in the console inside catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You specify parameter 6 twice. First you need to fix that and change email parameter index to 7 like below.

```
pst.setString(7, Email=EmTxt.getText());
```

Secondly, you need to remove 1 question mark from insert string as you only provide 7 input.

```
String query="insert into student.student values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Update: Please provide the column names in your insert string also. Without column names database doesn’t know which column you are skipping.

Comment: Just did that,remove a question mark and replace the incorrect 6 to 7 got a new error i posted it below the old error message

Comment: I changed the numbers and started from 0 but now I get java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 ).

Comment: @J.DoeKl, The number should NOT start at 0. Starting at 1 is correct. What do you think the error message means. You know your database better than we do. Only you know how many columns you really have in your database. So make sure the parameters you specify match the columns in your database.

Comment: Well its 8 but im only inserting data into 7 of the columns because the last one is a column where i need to insert multiple values from an array into it so but i havent figured that out yet so i was just testing to see if this was working

Comment: With the numbers starting at 1 I get java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Exactly. What do you think the message is telling you??? You just stated: *Well its 8 but im only inserting data into 7* - do you think the error is complaining about that? I'm not an SQL expert but I would guess If you have 8 columns I would guess you need to provide 8 values?

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void AddBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
String Fname=FnTxt.getText();
String Lname=LnTxt.getText();
String Email=EmTxt.getText();

Integer age=Integer.parseInt(ITxt.getText());
String num=NumTxt.getText();
String gen = null;
Integer stuId;
String course;
ArrayList<String> courlist = null;
if (BioBox.isSelected())
{
    courlist.add("Biology");
}

if(EngBox.isSelected())
{
    courlist.add("English");
}

if(MathBox.isSelected())
{
    courlist.add("Mathematics");

}

if (hkBox.isSelected())
{
    courlist.add("Housekeeping");
}

if(FpBox.isSelected())
{
    courlist.add("Food Preparation");
}
if(webBox.isSelected())
{
    courlist.add("Web Design");
}

course="Test";
Connection conn=null;

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/students", "root","Splash7727#" );

     PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement("insert into students.studentinfo values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ");
     stuId=Integer.parseInt(ITxt.getText());
     pst.setInt(1,stuId);
     pst.setString(2,Fname);
     pst.setString(3,Lname);
         if(FRBtn.isSelected())
{
    gen="Female";
}
else if(MRBtn.isSelected())
{
    gen="Male";
}

     pst.setString(4, gen);
     age=Integer.parseInt(ageTxt.getText());
     pst.setInt(5,age);
     pst.setString(6, num);
     pst.setString(7,Email);

     pst.setString(8,course);

     pst.execute();

}catch(Exception e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}


}
```